Force Sphinx to Use Different Version of Python
I am running into a roadblock with configuring Sphinx and Python.
On my RHEL8 machine, I've installed the Python package Sphinx 7.3.7, which is located in the following directory: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
When executing the command "sphinx-build --version" it is outputting "sphinx-build 5.3.0" which is a package installed for Python 3.6 located at: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/.
I want to use Python 3.10 to build all Sphinx docs, so what would be the correct way to get the command "sphinx-build --version", to output "sphinx-build 7.3.7", which would indicate it is using Python 3.10 for Sphinx builds?

Tools like pyenv/poetry are there for such purposes, but to find tutorials and learn them you should use a search engine, not here.
